# Encoding field is specified without a type; the type cannot be automatically inferred because the data is not specified as a pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, altair

**Getting following error**

raise ValueError("{} encoding field is specified without a type; "
ValueError: vipin encoding field is specified without a type; the type cannot be automatically inferred because the data is not specified as a pandas.DataFrame.

```
import pyodbc
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
connection = pyodbc.connect(Driver='{SQL Server};',
                            server='server\SQLEXPRESS',
                            Database='DB',
                            uid ='UID',
                            pwd='pwd',
                            # Trusted_Connection='yes;'
                            )
cursor = connection.cursor()
df = pd.read_sql_query(' SELECT distinct EDITWHO,EDITDate FROM ddd where editwho is not null ',connection);
print(df)
for item, row in df.iterrows():
    chart =alt.Chart(row).mark_bar().encode(
        x=row['EDITWHO'],
        y=row['EDITDate']
)
chart.save('chart.html')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Altair accepts dataframes for the data argument, and column names for the encodings. You are passing a series for the data argument, and data values for the encodings. Intead of iterating through the rows, you probably mean to do something like this:

```python
chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
  x='EDITWHO',
  y='EDITDate',
)
chart.save('chart.html')
```