# specified without a type

Tags: python, dataframe, altair

I tried to filter some datas from a csv file. It worked fine. Now i wanted to do some graphs with altair. I imported it already.

```
Forest=pd.read_csv("AnnualChangeForest.csv", sep=',')
Forest


print(Forest.loc[[46, 47, 48, 49, 81, 82, 83, 84, 444, 445, 446 ]])


            Entity Code  Year  Annual net change in forest area
46          Brazil  BRA  1990                        -3780940.0
47          Brazil  BRA  2000                        -3950790.0
48          Brazil  BRA  2010                        -1539180.0
49          Brazil  BRA  2015                        -1453040.0
81           China  CHN  1990                         1986000.0
82           China  CHN  2000                         2360980.0
83           China  CHN  2010                         1936770.0
84           China  CHN  2015                         1936790.0
444  United States  USA  1990                          108600.0
445  United States  USA  2000                          518400.0
446  United States  USA  2010                          275000.0

Forest2=print(Forest.loc[[46, 47, 48, 49, 81, 82, 83, 84, 444, 445, 446 ]])

alt.Chart(Forest2).mark_bar().encode(
    x="Year",
    y="Annual net change in forest area",
)


Year encoding field is specified without a type; the type cannot be automatically inferred because the data is not specified as a pandas.DataFrame.
```

I wanted to do some Charts. In the result i got an error message. I think it is because "Forest2" wasnt read with the "reading csv" command.

What do i have to know to get the chart working with "Forest2"

Thank you. If i have made any mistakes in this forum according to the rules, i apologize. Its my first post here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Encoding field is specified without a type; the type cannot be automatically inferred because the data is not specified as a pandas.DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64943607/encoding-field-is-specified-without-a-type-the-type-cannot-be-automatically-inf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following line is the issue.

```
Forest2=print(Forest.loc[[46, 47, 48, 49, 81, 82, 83, 84, 444, 445, 446 ]])
```

`print` function doesn't return anything, so `None` is getting assigned to the `Forest2` variable.

It should be

```
Forest2= Forest.loc[[46, 47, 48, 49, 81, 82, 83, 84, 444, 445, 446 ]]
```

Comment: Happy to help, and please close the question as well.